# WPF, XAML, FindAncestor binding DataTemplate/ControlTemplate hierarchy

Tags: wpf, xaml

We have the following XAML:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PictureMediaEditorInformationTemplate" DataType="mediaEditorInformation:PictureMediaEditorInformation">
        <dxlc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal">
            <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{Binding LabelContent}">
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{Binding LabelTitle}" LabelPosition="Left">
                        <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                    <dxlc:LayoutItem>
                        <dxe:ImageEdit ShowLoadDialogOnClickMode="Empty" ShowBorder="true" AllowDrop="True" Drop="PictureEditor_OnDrop"
                    Source="{Binding VisibleImage, Converter={StaticResource LexImageToImageConverter}, 
                    Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="320" Height="320" ShowMenu="true">
                            <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="MouseDoubleClick" Command="{Binding ViewPictureCommand}"/>
                            </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <dxe:ImageEdit.MenuTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <dxe:ImageEditClearToolButton ImageSource="{Binding ButtonImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=dxlc:LayoutGroup}}"/>
```

And we can't work out the correct way to specify the DataTemplate datacontext for the ImageSource binding. It might be complicated by the fact that the DataTemplate is a resource instantiated in code using:

```
var template = (DataTemplate) lg.FindResource(item.DataTemplateName);

            var uiElement = template.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
```

We've tried various things but with no success so far. I had hoped that setting uiElement.Name could be used in conjunction with ElementName but it fails presumably because it's crossing from a ControlTemplate to a DataTemplate.

NB:In the actual code the property is not called 'Wibble' :)

Comment: You don't usually "specify" the DataContext of the elements in a DataTemplate, because the DataContext is automatically set to an instance of DataType, e.g. PictureMediaEditorInformation here. There should be a public VisibleImage property in class PictureMediaEditorInformation.

Comment: There is such a property, and the ImageEdit is binding to it, that's not the problem. The problem was the last binding which complained that the property 'Wibble' couldn't be found on ImageEdit. However I've since realised that specifying the path solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to specify a path in the binding:

```
<dxe:ImageEditClearToolButton ImageSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Wibble}"
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of writing an answer.

Comment: I thought if we knew the answer that's what we were supposed to do? https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Ok, it looked like you forgot to show something in the question. That said, it's still hard to understand how this is related to the question. Does it replace `ImageSource="{Binding ButtonImage ...}"` (where ButtonImage also is a valid property path)? IMO this will never be of much help for others and may as well be deleted entirely.